# Java regex to parse /robots.txt

Tags: java, regex, web-crawler, robots.txt

I am trying to find a proper regex to parse a robots.txt file.

So what I am doing is taking the page into a string that looks like this one for example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /a
Disallow: /b/c
Disallow: /d/c/h

User-agent: agent1
Disallow: /a1/c1
Disallow: /b1/d1

User-agent: agent2
Disallow: /a2/c2
Disallow: /b2/d2
```

So what I am trying to do is to create a **regex** to take for each User-agent the agent name (*,agent1,agent2) and its Disallow list.

Here is code I've tried, but I am not getting what I expect:

```
public void parseRobotsTxt() {
    String website = "http://http://www.EXAMPLE.com";
    String content = PageUtils.getStringSource(website + "/robots.txt");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?User-agent:(.*?)(Disallow:(.*?))",Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("The user agent:" + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("Disallow List: ");
        System.out.println("The user agent:" + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("----------------------");
    }

}
```

Unfortunately the result I am getting is

```
The user agent: *    
Disallow List: 
Disallow:
----------------------
The user agent: agent1
Disallow List: 
Disallow:
----------------------
The user agent: agent2    
Disallow List: 
Disallow:
----------------------
```

I am getting the agent name but not the disallow list.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to: Split by newline - check that the first line starts with `User-agent:` and extract it - while lines start with `Disallow` add them to your record - when an empty line is met, start a new record?

Comment: Wouldn't String#split be easier? You could get an array of each user-agent and parse the remaining text.

Comment: Forgive my glibness, but the [“two problems” quote](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) seems relevant here.  This parsing is easily done without regular expressions.

Comment: Why a regex? You can use regexes for this in a different way, but you need several of them. You're ignoring `Allow:` too.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly your question, you want to capture the user agent name and their disallow list.

To do this I can come up with a simple regex like this:

```
User-agent: (.*)|Disallow: (.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/RLum7s/1)**

The idea is to capture in group 1 the agent name and in group 2 the disallow list. Here you have the match information

```
Match 1        Group 1. 12-13   `*`
Match 2            Group 2. 24-26   `/a`
Match 3            Group 2. 37-41   `/b/c`
Match 4            Group 2. 52-58   `/d/c/h`
Match 5        Group 1. 72-78   `agent1`
Match 6            Group 2. 89-95   `/a1/c1`
Match 7            Group 2. 106-112 `/b1/d1`
Match 8        Group 1. 126-132 `agent2`
Match 9            Group 2. 143-149 `/a2/c2`
Match 10           Group 2. 160-166 `/b2/d2`
```

Comment: It's working somehow, Thanks. It's not that ok because the 'Dissallow' list for each user-agent should be at a one time Match. It's ok

Comment: @DragosRoban, regex is the right tool for pattern match, but what you want is to have a regex with logic which is not the rigth tool for that. If you need to do logic you have to use another tool or help your pattern matching with regex and use code to group the content. Also keep in mind that the regex i gave you is pretty readable and simple, if you want to have a regex with logic it will be a horrible pattern almost impossible to understand, or at least at the top of my mind